# How to convert List<Object[]> to List<SimpleAccount> in Java?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using JDK 12, Spring Boot 2.1.5.RELEASE , Spring Data JPA. I follow guide at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting

I have Repository

```
package com.example.repository;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.example.entity.Account;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT a.id, a.accountNumber, a.accountName FROM Account a WHERE a.grade = 2")
    List<Object[]> findAllAccount(Sort sort);

}
```

and

```
package com.example.dto;

public class SimpleAccount {

    private Integer id;
    private String accountNumber;
    private String accountName;

    public SimpleAccount() {

    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

}
```

entity `Account` has more fields than entity `SimpleAccount` .

at controller

```
package com.example.controller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.example.common.UtilityList;
import com.example.dto.SimpleAccount;
import com.example.entity.Account;
import com.example.repository.AccountRepository;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/accounts_mulcol_json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public String accountsMulColJSON() throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<Object[]> accountsList = accountRepository.findAllAccount(Sort.by("accountNumber"));
        List<SimpleAccount> simpleAccountList = new ArrayList<>();
```

How to convert `List<Object[]>` to `List<SimpleAccount>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution would be to write a constructor for `SimpleAccount` class like this:

```
public SimpleAccount(Object[] objects) {
    setId((Integer) objects[0]);
    setAccountNumber((String) objects[1]);
    setAccountName((String) objects[2]);
}
```

And then map `List<Object[]>` to `List<SimpleAccount>` like this:

```
List<SimpleAccount> simpleAccountList = accountRepository.findAllAccount(Sort.by("accountNumber")).stream().map(SimpleAccount::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Create additional constructor for `SimpleAccount`

```
public SimpleAccount(Integer id, String accountNumber, String accountName) {
    ...
}
```

and define your `@Query` this way:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.dto.SimpleAccount(a.id, a.accountNumber, a.accountName) FROM Account a WHERE a.grade = 2")
List<SimpleAccount> findAllAccount(Sort sort);
```

If you need to convert `List<Object[]>` to `List<SimpleAccount>` manually, so create again new constructor

```
public SimpleAccount(Object[] data) {
    this.id = (Integer) data[0];
    this.accountNumber = (String) data[1];
    ...
}
```

Now, when you get `List<Object[]>` from database, iterate over list and call contstructor:

```
List<Object[]> accountsList = accountRepository.findAllAccount(Sort.by("accountNumber"));
List<SimpleAccount> simpleAccountList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object[] obj: accountsList) {
    simpleAccountList.add(new SimpleAccount(obj));
}
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful. Can you convert `List<Object[]>` to `List<SimpleAccount>`?

Comment: No need to do that. Spring does the magic. Just copy-paste the solution as is and it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return Account instead of Object[]

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Account a WHERE a.grade = 2")
List<Account> findAllAccount(Sort sort);
```

Comment: I try to reach good performance. Can you help me SELECT few fields, not SELECT all fields? And I need a generalization when I query from more than one table?